# To count the number of square integers between AA and BB (both inclusive) output shows run time error when both are 9 digits

Tags: c++, algorithm

This is my code:

```
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdio>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int t;long long a, b;long long x; //declartion
cin>>t;                    //1≤T≤1001≤T≤100  
if(t<1||t>100)
    exit(0);
for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
   long long c=0;
cin>>a>>b;
if(a>b||a<1||a>pow(10,9)||b<1)         //1≤A≤B≤109
    exit(0);
for(long long y=a;y<=b;y++){
    x= floor(sqrt(y));
    if(pow(x,2)==y){
        c++;
    }
   }cout<<c<<endl;
}

return 0;`
}
```

Watson gives two integers (AA and BB) to Sherlock and asks if he can count the number of square integers between AA and BB (both inclusive).

Please tell me why I am getting error time?

Comment: Did you try using a debugger? What is the range of numbers AA and BB?

Comment: 1≤T≤100 //1≤A≤B≤10^9

Comment: Are you sure it is run time error and not time out or incorrect answer. Code doesn't seem to have run time error. But can give incorrect answer and is not implemented most efficiently. Do you know the inputs for which this fails?

Comment: t= 100 //for understanding purpose,
a=385793959 b=712365911
,8402731 222972782
,168688344 715650822
,120807850 560224235
,336504559 547471834
,93616897 674174001
,180249517 553442334.....

Comment: few results says its time out ? what should i do for it ?

Comment: `pow(x,2)` is a terrible way to square a number - also the mixing of ints and doubles is haphazard and inefficient.

Comment: solution ? any other way to eliminate it?

Comment: `x*x` and put more spaces to your code more readable. `if(a>b||a<1||a>pow(10,9)||b<1)` eww

Comment: Also note that there is a much better algorithm which you can use which does not involve `sqrt` or examining every number between AA and BB.

Answer (score 0):

[From comments]
Your code appears to run slower than the allowed time line. You can use the following algorithm to speed up.

```
 1. sz = 0, arr[sqrt(1000 * 1000 * 1000) + 5]
 2. While sz * sz < (1000 * 1000 * 1000)
   2.1 arr[sz] = sz * sz
   2.2 sz = sz + 1
 3. Read T, repeat for all T
   3.1 Read aa and bb
   3.2 Use binary search to find upperbound of aa and bb in arr.
   3.3 Print the difference of indices
```

If I boil down to following lines of code in C++:

```
int ai = isqrt(aa), bi = isqrt(bb);
return bi - ai + 1;
```

You can find the algorithm for `isqrt` @ [Methods_of_computing_square_roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Example_2)

```
int isqrt(int num) {
    int res = 0;
    int bit = 1 << 30;

    while (bit > num)
        bit >>= 2;

    while (bit != 0) {
        if (num >= res + bit) {
            num -= res + bit;
            res = (res >> 1) + bit;
        }
        else
            res >>= 1;
        bit >>= 2;
    }
    return res;
}
```